# What code can I use for authentication of users through login control?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Where should I type the authentication code in order to validate the users trying to login to the website.

I have used *login control* in my website. Also I would appreciate few examples of codes which are generally used in authentication code.

Answer (score 1):

.net has templates for login pages, password recovery, etc.

simply google for it or go here:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sushmita_kumari/Logincontrol101312006002845AM/Logincontrol1.aspx?ArticleID=c33d0072-8f7c-4958-a7dc-ca1809737193
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you mean. If you're using a Login control they can already authenticate with that.

Do you mean authorization? You need to check users are authorized to access your site if it is restricted to logged in users only. Say you have a part of your site called "importantstuff" that only logged in users can access. i.e. www.yoursite.com/importantstuff/. You would put this in your web.config outside of the `<system.web></system.web>` tags:

```
  <location path="importantstuff">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

This would prevent unauthenticated users from accessing anything in the "importantstuff" directory.